# Extraer valor de array multiple dependiendo de otro valor

Tags: php

Estoy intentando mostrar unos datos extraídos de una API por JSON y estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar uno de ellos (soy novato en PHP). Al imprimir el array en cuestión de muestra lo siguiente:

```
array(118) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1280)
      ["name"]=>
      string(18) "Tina Zarpa Fangosa"
      ["standing"]=>
      int(3)
      ["value"]=>
      int(3015)
      ["max"]=>
      int(8400)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1281)
      ["name"]=>
      string(18) "Gina Zarpa Fangosa"
      ["standing"]=>
      int(4)
      ["value"]=>
      int(1820)
      ["max"]=>
      int(8400)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1282)
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Pez Junco Talado"
      ["standing"]=>
      int(3)
      ["value"]=>
      int(1508)
      ["max"]=>
      int(8400)
    }
}
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando el ID de una de las entradas sea, por ejemplo, 1281, imprima el string de "name" ("Gina Zarpa Fangosa", en el ejemplo).
A ver si alguien puede echarme un cable, que debe ser simple pero tengo la cabeza embotada con tanto foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que le damos de nombre personas al array seria:

```
$personas[1281]['name']
```

Comment: **Eso no funciona**. Busca por el campo propio id de cada ocurrencia del array, no por el identificador del array.

Comment: suponía que era el principal, pero si es el otro campo, puedes recorrer con un foreach($personas as $key => $value) o usar la funcion array_search()

Comment: Finalmente lo he hecho con lo que aportabas en tu otro comentario, con array_search():

$llave = array_search(1281, array_column($value, 'id'));
              foreach ($value[$llave] as $key => $value) {
                switch ($key) {
                  case 'name':
                    echo "Nombre: ".$value;
                    break;
                  ...
                }

Comment: @Frandalf en realidad no es un comentario es una respuesta del usuario JDev.

Answer (score 0):

Recorre el array hasta que lo encuentres

```
foreach($array as $item){
    if($item["id"] == $valorBuscado){
        $nameBuscado = $item["name"];
        break;
    }
}
```